# How to apply ngClass to element based stated?

Tags: angular

I have a service that stores a state of opened block as:

```
export class BlocksStateService {
   public openedBlockState = new Map<number, boolean>;

   setState(id: number, state: boolean) {
     this.openedBlockState.set(id, state);
   }
  
   getState(id: number): boolean {
      return this.openedBlockState.get(id);
   }
}
```

I use this class in component:

```
public isBlockOpened(id: number): boolean {
     return this.blocksStateService.getState(id);
}
```

Then in template:

```
<div [class.opened]="isBlockOpened(id)"></div>
```

I know using function in template is bad practice. How to apply model data to ngClass more properly?

Comment: You can use function in ngClass also but to use the model data in ngClass, the model variable should be present in the component itself and with public visibility

Comment: Could you share an example? Is it possible to use pipes?

Comment: The solution that I have in mind will avoid the use of `BlockStateService` and move the `openedBlockState` map to the component itself then use it in ngClass like `[ngClass]={'opened': openBlockState.get(id)}` but I don't think thats a good idea either because use of service is a good practice.

Comment: I can not move state in component, because component recreates so I lose a state

Comment: why not assign the state to a local field on component init?

Answer (score 1):

Method expression for ngClass

```
<div [ngClass]="getSomeClass(id)"></div>
```

and method in your component

```
getSomeClass(id){
     var   isBlockOpened =  this.blocksStateService.getState(id);
   if (isBlockOpened) 
   {
    return "class.opened"
   } 
  else
  {
    return "class.close"
  }  
}
```

Comment: I said that I try to avoid using functons in template

Comment: ok, one more options will be to create property in component and set the value for this property in function and bind this property with ngClass

Comment: I can not move state in component, because component recreates so I lose a state

Comment: where you set the state ? openedBlockState.set(id, state)? where this will set the state?

Comment: Check my question please

Comment: you can use localStorage and set the state in  localStorage. if component recreates, you will have state in localStorage

Comment: you don't actually show how you're calling `setState` in your question, which is what @NAS is asking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ngClass of angular,

First of all you can change your component isBlockOpened funtion

```
public isBlockOpened(id: number): boolean {
     return this.blocksStateService.getState(id) ? true : false;
}
```

Then you need to change your component.html file

```
<div [ngClass]="{'opened': isBlockOpened(id)}"></div>
```

Comment: I dont want to call function from template.